# Swift keyboard problem on presented view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, keyboard

I am getting a problem with keyboard on presented view controller. I am presenting a bottom sheet from a controller. At this bottom sheet, I have a textView with becomeFirstResponder() delegate at viewDidLayoutSubViews(). But keyboard is pushing presented view controller like in picture. How can I present keyboard above presented view controller without pushing page ?

[keyboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqY6p.png)

Comment: Is there any idea ?

Comment: The issue is not clear by the description, can you add more details.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it using this code:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    tableview.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

It does not let the inset of titleText/placeHolder be changed